# Seaborn residplot not outputting the plot

Tags: python, seaborn, linear-regression

Hi I'm trying to create residplot using seaborn.
I have my true values in one np.array and my predictions in another.
sns.residplot(x=y_pred, y=y_true) however seaborn outputs only an empty plot:
[image]

I checked for nans and removed them. Also tried to call them from a data frame:
sns.residplot(x='y_pred', y='y_true', data=df) # where 'y_pred' and 'y_true' are columns in the df.
However I always get an empty plot.
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Impossible to know without looking at the data, but that's not how you're supposed to use `residplot()`, you should pass `x` and `y`, not `y` and `y`

Comment: works for me.. can you share how your data looks like